# Show the same rank in drill through report as the same in Summary report

Tags: cognos, cognos-10, cognos-bi, cognos-8

I have a report in which I display the Student Name, their marks and the rank based on the marks.On clicking on the student name a drill through report opens and their details are displayed. In the drill through report also I have to show the rank of the student. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is to have a your student rank value be part of what you send as part of the drill-through to the student detail query. Then just display the passed value as part of the query result via a list or elsewhere.

Comment: Take look at the document at the following link. It walks you through an example of what you need to do.

https://du1ux2871uqvu.cloudfront.net/sites/default/files/file/Drill-through-reports-revised.pdf